# Displaying a div in an iframe out of it

Tags: html, iframe

I am having a div in an iframe which appears when we click in an input box.

iframe looks like this

```
<iframe src='mycontrol.html' width='300' height='50' />
```

Below is code for mycontrol.html

```
<div>
    <input type='text' />
    <div style='height:80px;'>
         This will be shown when we click in the above text box.
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the javascript to show the div when user clicks the input box, problem is that since this div is more in height than the height of iframe and is not displayed completely. Some area from the bottom of div was cut due to iframe.

My question, is there anyway to show complete div with javascript or css without resizing the iframe ??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need? It doesn't exactly get the `div` break out of the `iframe` but it looks like it would. Working demo at [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/n5nds/1/)

In the main page:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#frame {
    width: 300px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-bottom: -70px;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <iframe id="frame" src="frame.htm" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<p>Some text below IFRAME in main window.</p>
```

In mycontrol.html:

```
BODY {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#div {
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ff0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: none;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="document.getElementById('div').style.display='block';" onblur="document.getElementById('div').style.display='none'";/>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: @silent-coder This wasn't what you want? Please post a comment, if you've further questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use css overflow:scroll for your iframe

```
iframe {
 overflow:scroll;
}
```